# How to get (new) mark on any folder/file icon in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, icons, directory

See what Dropbox desktop application does is it puts a check mark on the files and folders that have synchronized with the cloud. I want something like that. I want to put a new mark on the folder or file created or edited with Java program.

How to get (new) mark on any folder/file icon in Windows?

Comment: Start by identifying the win32 libraries that would provide this service, then find a JNA or write a JNI solution that allows you to achieve it...

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Actually its a part of bigger application developed in java.

Comment: Cool, but what are you going to do for Mac. and *nix?  It will likely require 3 different types of native code!  @MadProgrammer showed the correct route you need to follow.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Wow, that makes a nice change ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  What's new?  You being modest about your abilities, or me being 'cool' about something?  ;)  (I'd reckon it's the latter.  ..It's a thing I'm trying out.)